# VBA EXCEL: Use value in Listbox as Lookup value in the Match WorksheetFunction

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how to lookup a value selected from a **Listbox** (clicked) using `application.worksheetfunction.match(lookup_value, lookuparray, match type)`

edit:

This is a "supposed" to be a button (Reservebutton) the "ReservationName" is a textbox the reserve button adds the number from the available listbox to the reserved listbox and then deletes the number selected in the available listbox. i'm a beginner in coding, so mind my mistakes please.
thanks a lot.

```
Private Sub ReserveButton_Click()

Dim Locator, RowData, NListBoxValue As Double
Locator = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Worksheets("Reserved").Range("A:A"))

For r = 0 To AvailableNumberList.ListCount - 1
RowData = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(AvailableNumberList.List(r), Worksheets("Activation").Range("A:A"), 0)

If AvailableNumberList.Selected(r) = True Then

If ReservationName.Value = "" Or ReservationName.Value = "Enter Full Name" Then
ErrorResult = MsgBox("Error: Name field is empty", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error In Field")
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(AvailableNumberList.List(r), Activation.Range("A:E"), 4, False) <> "FREE" Then
ErrorResult = MsgBox("Error: Number is Not Free", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error In Reservation")
Else
ReservedNumberList.AddItem AvailableNumberList.List(r)
Worksheets("Reserved").Range("A" & Locator + 2) = AvailableNumberList.List(r)
Worksheets("Reserved").Range("B" & Locator + 2) = Worksheets("Activation").Cells(RowData, 2)
Worksheets("Reserved").Range("C" & Locator + 2) = Worksheets("Activation").Cells(RowData, 3)
Worksheets("Reserved").Range("D" & Locator + 2) = ReservationName.Value

AvailableNumberList.Clear
Worksheets("Reserved").Rows(RowData).Delete
ThisWorkbook.Save
Call AvailableList

End If

End If

Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to return from the function?

Comment: The position of the value in the range. @jbarker2160

Comment: Row or column or both?

Comment: Do you have a way to get the row? MATCH only works with 1-dimensional arrays.

Comment: The column is always "A:A"

Comment: Is the value from the ListBox you want to match in the `BoundColumn`?

Comment: i'm receiving a run-time error 1004

Comment: I can't really help if I don't see your code.

Comment: @jbarker2160 done. you may find the code in the edited question.

Comment: You are nor referencing the range as I showed in my answer.  Change `Worksheets("Activation").Range("A:A")` to `Range("Activation!A:A")`

Comment: did that, sorry i still have the same issue.

Comment: Is it the Match line that's giving the error?  It's gonna be difficult to troubleshoot this without the actual workbook, though.

Comment: I've worked it out. Thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: @jbarker2160 i'll +1 your answer when i get enough user points. You have been of great help. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(<Form>.<Listbox>,Range("<LookupSheet>!A:A"),0)
```